# Error: control reaches end of non-void function?

Tags: c++

This is my assignment : " Write a function that finds the larger of two integers input (in the main program) but allows you to change the value of the integers in the function using pass by reference." I been trying to find out whats wrong with my code but I cant find out what it is. Someone please help me !! this assignment is due tonight!! 
Here is my code as of right now :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int change(int& x, int& y)

{
    int temp=0;

    cout << "Function(before change): " << x << " " << y << endl;

    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;

    cout << "Function(after change): " << x << " " << y << endl;

}

int main()

{
    int x,y;

    cout << " Please Enter your first number: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << " Please Enter your second number: ";
    cin >> y;

    if (x > y)
        cout << x << " is greater than " << y << endl;

    if (x < y)
        cout << y << " is greater than " << x << endl;

    if (x == y)
        cout << x << " is equal to " <<y << endl;

    cout << "Main (before change): " << x << " " << y << endl;
    change(x, y);

    cout << "Main (after change): " << x << " " << y << endl;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You specify that `change` will return an `int` but you never return anything.

Comment: Keyword: Return value.

Answer (score 3):

`change` is declared as returning an `int`, but it never returns anything. It doesn't look like your function *should* return anything, so just declare it as `void`:

```
void change(int& x, int& y)
```